# How do I delete all the comments in all the project from Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

I need to modify a code but it has so many unused comments like this:

```
/*   6:    */ import java.util.List;
/*   7:    */ import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
/*   8: 7  */ import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
/*   9:    */ import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
/*  10:    */ import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I  can give one alternative way .I 'm using this method.

There is a option `search and replace` in netbeans. Enable regex option and then type a regex to match the comments and replace with empty character. go to `edit` menu and then `replace`.

use regex

```
/\\*.*?\\*/
```

to match `/*comment*/` style comment

`edit > replace`

example

[image]

I think it's not hard to create a `netbeans` `addon` to do this with a button .

Also `rectangular selection tool` can be helpful some times if the area is a rectangle

example

[image]

Comment: There is a risky case, if you have defined url in your class, this regular expression will be replace "//" symbols also. For example :   String url = "http://www.google.com";  will be replaced to String url = "http:www.google.com";

Comment: agreed, any URLs within the CSS (for example /image/123.jpg) are now just 123.jpg, the / and insides are removed!

Nice answer though and great GIFs, great effort put into the answer indeed.
I think they should use yours but maybe manually supervise it! :)